# Query Over StartsWith

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have to try finding results based on search, which should be startswith, but I cannot find `QueryOver` which has startswith, is there any otherway ?

```
public IEnumerable<Company> Find(string keyword)
{
     var sesion = SessionController.CurrentSession;
     return sesion.QueryOver<Company>()
     .Where(
        Restrictions.On<Company>(x => x.CompanyName).IsLike("%" + keyword + "%") ||
        Restrictions.On<Company>(x => x.Id).IsLike("%" + keyword + "%")
     )
     .List<Company>();
}
```

Comment: You mean any other way than removing the leading % in your IsLike restrictions ?

Answer (score 11):

The way, supported by `QueryOver` infrastructure would be to use explicit `MatchMode`:

```
sesion
  .QueryOver<Company>()
  .Where
  (
     Restrictions.On<Company>(x => x.CompanyName).IsLike(keyword, MatchMode.Start) ||
     Restrictions.On<Company>(x => x.Id         ).IsLike(keyword, MatchMode.Start)
  )
  .List<Company>();
```

But with a very few code *(custom extension in the `Restrictions.On` style)*  we can even achieve this syntax:

```
...
.Where
(
   Restrict.On<Contact>(x => x.CompanyName).StartsWith(keyword) ||
   Restrict.On<Contact>(x => x.Id         ).StartsWith(keyword)
)
```

And the definition of the `Restrict`:

```
public static class Restrict
{
    public static StringRestrictionBuilder<T> On<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
    {
        return new StringRestrictionBuilder<T>(expr);
    }
    public class StringRestrictionBuilder<T>
    {
        readonly Expression<Func<T, object>> _expression;
        public StringRestrictionBuilder(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
        {
            _expression = expression;
        }
        public AbstractCriterion StartsWith(string value)
        {
            return Restrictions.On(_expression).IsLike(value, MatchMode.Start);
        }
        public AbstractCriterion Contains(string value)
        {
            return Restrictions.On(_expression).IsLike(value, MatchMode.Anywhere);
        }
        public AbstractCriterion EndsWith(string value)
        {
            return Restrictions.On(_expression).IsLike(value, MatchMode.End);
        }
    }
}
```